# Find the position of first negative number in a R vector that may be entirely positive

Tags: r

Let's say I have a vector drawn from a normal distribution.

```
RandomVector<-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=1)
> RandomVector
[1]  1.18186018  0.53810223  0.33888370  0.46593762  2.33963330 -0.08779368     -0.65178144 -0.61384231 -0.74351425
[10] -0.51577616
```

I want to find the **position** of the first number <=0 in the vector. The simplest way would be to use which.

```
FirstNegative<-min(which(RandomVector<=0))
```

However, in some cases the vector may have no negative numbers, in which case which( ) will return a vector of length zero.

```
> RandomVector
 [1] 1.20150245 0.58668248 1.65633049 1.63277953 0.51134272 0.76385987 0.89085391 0.06504819 0.18011920 0.02400666
```

This will give you an error.

```
> FirstNegative<-min(which(RandomVector<0))
Warning message:
In min(which(RandomVector < 0)) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Here are some solutions to this problem that I've come up with. All of them work, but I want to avoid an if/else statement if possible. Can anyone think of a more concise way?

```
for (j in 1:length(RandomVector)) {
        if (RandomVector[j]<=0) {
            FirstNegative<-j
            break;
            }
```

Alternatively...

```
WhichNegative<-which(RandomVector<=0)
if (length(WhichNegative)>0) {
    FirstNegative<-min(WhichNegative)
    }
```

Same basic idea, but still using an if statement

```
 if (any(RandomVector<=0)==TRUE) {
     FirstNegative<-min(which(RandomVector<=0))
     }
```

The reason I'm asking is because this check will be made for a large number of vectors of long length. Plus I'm just curious.

Comment: `min(min(which(RandomVector<=0)), -99)` , if it returns negative, you can assume it did not meet the condition. Not sure if you were looking for something similar.

Comment: Maybe `Position(function(x) x<=0,data)[1]`? will return `NA` if there are no negatives.

Comment: `Position(function(x) x<=0,data)[1]` does give an NA, much better than integer(0). Thanks

Comment: `rv <- RandomVector <= 0; if(sum(rv) == 0L) NA else which.max(rv)` should do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution**

You can use:

```
FirstNegative <- which(RandomVector <= 0)[1]
```

Which will return the position of the first element less than or equal to zero, or `NA` if nothing is applicable. You can then catch the `NA` and do whatever you would like.

**Comment**

The reason `min` returns an error is because it expects an input of length greater than zero.

Your first method of searching for the first negative is quite computationally expensive, as you may have to go through every element of the vector. Binomial search may be a quicker method.

The second and third methods are fine, the second will be quicker than the third as in the third you will go through the vector twice, once to find any element less than or equal to zero, then to find the first.

Ultimately though, the method given in solution will be quickest, as `which` returns a sorted list, and therefore `min` doesn't do anything useful as the minimum will always be the first element.

Comment: I don't think the first method is more computationally expensive than needed. This is a random vector, how can you get the result without potentially look for every element? The reason of it is being slow is because explicit loop in R is slower than vectorized functions.